# Using the 'soul' package to redefine \emph -> Problems in Bibtex

Tags: spacing, bibtex, soul

I was planning on using the soul package to redefine \emph to \so, so that everytime I use \emph, the text would not be italics but l i k e  t h i s (spacing out, so).

However, once I use

```
\usepackage{soul}
\renewcommand{\emph}{\so}
```

in my document, my bibtex (to be precise: biber) bibliography wont show up any text which normally is italics, i.e. book titles, journal titles, etc. Now I would like the bib to use italics instead of spaced-out, but I guess bibtex uses \emph...

Is there a way around this, besides using \so directly in my main text, because Im not 100% sure I will want to go with it and normally this is latex strong suit, that I could change it back in retrospect. I guess in case I wanted it back, I could redefine \so, but thats not very neat.
Maybe I can redefine emph back to its normal function before the bib is printed? How? If I naively type

```
\renewcommand{\emph}{\emph}
```

latex wont compile.

Its not a biggy, but I thought Id ask, if anyone has an idea.

Thanks!

Comment: `\renewcommand\emph{\emph}` does create an infinite loop, since `\emph` now expands to `\emph`, which expands to `\emph`, which expands to `\emph`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\NewCommandCopy` if you're using a recent LaTeX installation to save the definition of `\emph` to later restore it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul}

\NewCommandCopy\emphorig\emph
\renewcommand\emph{\so}

\begin{document}
\emph{This is emphasised}

\renewcommand\emph{\emphorig}% or \let\emph\emphorig
\emph{This is emphasised}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If your LaTeX installation is a bit dated and the above doesn't work, you can instead use the `letltxmacro` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{soul}

\LetLtxMacro\emphorig\emph
\renewcommand\emph{\so}

\begin{document}
\emph{this is emphasised}

\let\emph\emphorig
\emph{this is emphasised}
\end{document}
```